# Why is my nested loop only picking up some items?

Tags: python

I'm trying to get the loop to go through all suits then all of the card numbers to create a deck of cards but it seems to be pulling alternating values.  I have the range set at the bottom as 26 because I was getting out of range errors going any higher.

```
import random


# actual deck creation using Card class
class Deck:

    def __init__(self):
        suits = ["Spades", "Clubs", "Hearts", "Diamonds"]
        numbers = {"two": ["Two", 2], "three": ["Three", 3], "four": ["Four", 4], "five": ["Five", 5],
                   "six": ["Six", 6],
                   "seven": ["Seven", 7], "eight": ["Eight", 8], "nine": ["Nine", 9], "ten": ["Ten", 10],
                   "jack": ["Jack", 10], "queen": ["Queen", 10], "king": ["King", 10], "ace": ["Ace", 1]}

        self.cards = []
        for suit in suits:
            for number in numbers.values():
                self.cards.append(Card(suit, number))

    def shuffledeck(self):
        random.shuffle(self.cards)
        return self.cards

    def cleardeck(self):
        self.cards = []
        return self.cards


class Card:

    def __init__(self, suit, value):
        self.suit = suit
        self.value = value

    # card print statement
    def __str__(self):
        return self.value + " of " + self.suit

class Game:
        def __init__(self):
            self.deck = []

        def play(self):
            self.deck = Deck()
            #self.deck.shuffledeck()


game = Game()
game.play()

#testing area
blah = []
for i in range(26):
     card = (game.deck.cards.pop(i))
     print(card.suit)
     blah.append(card.value)

print(str(blah))
```

Comment: I highly recommend that you debug your code by stepping though it line-by line. PyCharm is a free Python IDE with a great debugger. [Here's](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/debugging-your-first-python-application.html) how to use it. Learning to debug your own code is an essential skill; there won't always be people online willing to do it for you.

Answer (score 0):

You are popping an item at a specific index, while increasing the index; this will not exhaust all the items in `game.deck.cards`. Try instead, for example,

```py
for i in range(52):
    card = (game.deck.cards.pop())
```

Or `pop(0)` if you want to preserve the order, although this is said to be slower than `pop()`. If you really don't need to empty `game.deck.cards`, then the following might be simpler:

```py
for card in game.deck.cards:
    print(card.suit)
    blah.append(card.value)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. That makes sense.